# JavaScript - detect input change on any input/select field on current modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal with ~20 input and select fields that the user is supposed to complete. I would like to a quick JavaScript check whether the field is empty or not after the user is navigating away / changing / etc. the field, but want to avoid having to copy paste the code below 20 times and personalize it for each field.

```
<!-- Holidex -->
<label>Holidex:</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" placeholder="What is your Holidex code?" id="addHolidex" name="addHolidex" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
</div>
<!-- /.Holidex -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#addHolidex').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('#addHolidex').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-warning');
  } else {
    $('#addHolidex').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-warning');
  }
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to have the code above check for any select / input field on my `NewUserModal`?

Thank you!

EDIT

So I fiddled around with the suggested codes below but only the following managed to halfway work:

```
$('.input-group').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
  }
});
```

Empty fields are being flagged correctly now, but fields with content do not have the `has-success` class added. Note that I have to apply this class to the `<div class="input-group">` element instead of the `input select` fields.

Any suggestions? I am running on bootstrap 3 if that helps.

**EDIT 2**

Still no result and quite frankly have had enough for today.
- select fields are either ignored or incorrectly flagged with `has-error` if pre-populated
- individual input fields seem to work more or less
- grouped input fields nestled in one `div` all turn red if one field is empty (eg. phone number + phone country both turn red of there is not country code entered)

```
// highlight empty fields in red
$('.input-group input, select').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste',function(){
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
  }
});
```

I basically would have to redo the whole design of my modal and I quite frankly dont want to go down that road. Not a fan of JS/ Jquery today.

Comment: `$('input, select').on` would do the task..

Comment: Thanks, but wouldnt that address all inputs and selects on the entire webpage? How can I limit this to the currently active modal only?

Comment: `$('activeModalSelector :input')`

Comment: `$('yourModalIdOrClass :input, yourModalIdOrClass select')` would do it for you...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this is what you're looking for but, why do not simply make your code more universal:

```
$('input').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-warning');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-warning');
    }
});
```

## EDIT

If you would like to specify a precise form, add an ID to your form :

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label>Holidex:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" placeholder="What is your Holidex code?" id="addHolidex" name="addHolidex" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
    </div>
</form>

$('#myForm input').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-warning');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-warning');
    }
});
```

Comment: does this also work with a modal id? respectively, does this work with input and select fields on that specific modal?

Comment: An ID is something unique. It should work on every HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to the input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control Input-to-verify" maxlength="5" placeholder="What is your Holidex code?" id="addHolidex" name="addHolidex" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
```

and then in javascript:

```
   $('.Input-to-verify').on('change',function(){
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-warning');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-warning');
  }
});
```

I hope this works

Comment: the id selector is wrong you can use $(this) intead of $('#addHolidex')

Comment: @hannan I like the idea, but cant get it to work with the `<div class="input-group">` element. Note that I am not applying the class to the `input` but rather the `div` tag.

Comment: @Armitage2k Your div is enclosing the input element right? so you can use $(this).parent().closest('div').addClass("Success-or-Error"); OR 
$(this).parent().closest('.input-group').addClass("Success-or-Error");

Comment: @C.Fasolin Thanks Ive made the changes

Comment: You can also use $('.input-group input').on('change',function(){

});

Just play with the selecters ;)

Comment: @hannan, honestly, forget it. I've been playing around with this for almost 3 hours now, have tried every possible combination and still cant get it to work the way I want. Select fields are highlighted in red when they have pre-populated content, grouped input fields are all red if just one field is empty, etc. I am letting this go, seriously not interested anymore. I suggest a bootstrap plugin that handles such things.